# Have compiler ignoring setting an argument register before calling function

Tags: c++, c, assembly, compiler-optimization, calling-convention

***TL;DR;*** I am looking for a standard way to basically tell the compiler to pass whatever happened to be in a given register to the next function.

Basically I have a function `int bar(int a, int b, int c)`. In some cases `c` is unused and I would like to be able to call `bar` in the cases where `c` is unused without modifying `rdx` in any way.

For example if I have

```
int foo(int a, int b) { 
    int no_init; 
    return bar(a, b, no_init); 
}
```

I would like the assembly to just be:

For a tailcall

```
    jmp bar
```

or for a normal call

```
   call bar
```

Note: `clang` generally produces what I am looking for. But I am unsure if this will always be the case in more complex functions and I am hoping to not have to check the assembly each time I build.

`GCC` produces:

For a tailcall

```
    xorl %edx, %edx
    jmp bar
```

or for a normal call

```
   xorl %edx, %edx
   call bar
```

I can get the results I want using inline assembly i.e changing `foo` (for tail calls) to

```
int foo(int a, int b) {
    asm volatile("jmp bar" : : :);
    __builtin_unreachable();
}
```

which compiles to just

```
   jmp bar
```

I understand that the performance implications of an `xorl %edx, %edx` is about as close to 0 as possible but

***I am wondering if there is a standard way to achieve this.***

I.e I can probably find a hack for it for any given case. But that will require me verifying the assembly each time. I am looking for a method that you can basically tell the compiler "pass whatever happened to be in register".

See for examples: https://godbolt.org/z/eh1vK8

Edit: This is happening with `-O3` set.

Comment: Does it still do this when compiling with optimisations?

Comment: Yes (godbolt link compiled with ```-O3```). Also note this is generally an issue with GCC. clang seems to do what I want be I an not sure if it will reliably do so. (and I dont want to have to check the assembly for each build)

Comment: Perhaps you can do one better, and use something like a weak alias to ensure that all callers of `foo` directly call `bar` instead.

Comment: It is poor form to modify your question in a way that moots or invalidates existing answers.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I see. Since there is not answer at the moment I figured it was worth it to edit so that question would clearly ask what I am after. What would you suggest?

Comment: If you're not looking for "standard" and you're not concerned with undefined behavior (with respect to the language standards), then you can only be interested in the code-generation behavior of some specific C implementation, for there cannot otherwise be any basis for an answer.  In that case, tag the implementation of interest.

Comment: @Noah, there *was* an answer -- mine -- at the time you modified the question to avoid  using the word "standard" and to remark that it had been a poor choice of words.  Indeed, I believe you had already commented on my answer, and I took the edits to be in response to some of my remarks there.  If that's indeed what happened then **it's rude**, and the right thing to do is roll back those edits.

Comment: It's not just rude, its not allowed to make changes to a question the invalidate existing answers.  I've rolled back the question accordingly.

Comment: @RossRidge is it fair to add an edit saying that "standard" was a poor word choice and to explain what I mean?

Comment: Not in a way that invalidates existing answers, as your edits did.   You've made it clear in comments what you wanted to say, there's no need to change the question.  Ask a new question if you want to ask a different question then the one you originally posted.

Comment: @Noah, if you find that you have asked a different question than you meant to do, and have received answers that are directed to what you actually asked but are not responsive to what you wanted to ask, then the best course of action is usually to ask what you really wanted to know as a new question.  Include a link to the original question, if you like.  Or if you are also getting answers to what you really wanted to know then maybe you just leave well enough alone.

Comment: @JohnBollinger, sorry for the lack of tact. Just trying to find an answer. "standard" is treated as a proper noun with respect to c/c++ which was not what I intended and I believed mislead potential answerers. Did not mean to be rude. Will make a new question in the future.

Comment: @Noah, to be clear, this is not a proper noun trap.  Pretty much all the C and C++ language semantics that can reasonably be characterized as little-'s' "standard" are such because they are defined by the relevant language specification document (the "Standard", if you wish).  There are other kinds of things that are "standard" in the sense of "conventional" or "idiomatic" or similar, but these are not the subject of your particular question.

Comment: The cleanest way to achieve the desired behaviour is to file a *missed optimisation* bug report with the gcc project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach that should work for gcc/clang on most platforms is to do

```
    int no_init; 
    asm("" : "=r" (no_init));
    return bar(a, b, no_init);
```

This way you don't have to lie to the compiler about the prototype of `bar` (whichc could break some calling conventions), and you fool the compiler into thinking `no_init` is really initialized.

I would wonder about an architecture like Itanium with its "trap bit" that causes a fault when an uninitialized register is accessed.  This code would probably not be safe there.

There is no portable way to get this behavior that I know of, but you could ifdef it:

```
#ifdef __GNUC__
#define UNUSED_INT ({ int x; asm("" : "=r" (x)); x; })
#else
#define UNUSED_INT 0
#endif
// ...
   bar(a, b, UNUSED_INT);
```

Then you can fall back to the (infinitesimally) less efficient but correct code when necessary.

It results in a bare `jmp` on gcc/x86-64, see https://godbolt.org/z/d3ordK.  On x86-32 it is not quite optimal as it pushes an uninitialized register, instead of just adjusting an existing subtraction from `esp`.  Note that a bare `jmp/call` is not safe on x86-32 because that third stack slot may contain something important, and the callee is allowed to overwrite it (even if the variable is unused on the path you have in mind, the compiler could be using it as scratch space).

One portable alternative would be to rewrite `bar` to be variadic.  However, then it would need to use `va_arg` to retrieve the third argument when it is present, and that tends to be less efficient.

Comment: This seems to work really well. Only issue I'm seeing is that if its not a tailcall clang goes a bit crazy.

Comment: @Noah: How do you mean?

Comment: it adds a ```push``` and ```pop```. Not sure why: https://godbolt.org/z/Pjh6oK

Comment: The `asm volatile` may be confusing the optimizer.  I suspect with normal code there it would do better.  Note that the same happens if you pass `0` for the third argument, so this looks like an unrelated missed optimization.

Comment: yeah that seems to be the case (without the ```asm volatile``` as well). https://godbolt.org/z/8xK84P

Comment: @Noah: In that one, using the stack is unavoidable, because `b` is in `esi` which the call to `bar()` may overwrite.  The compiler saves it in `ebx`, which is callee-saved, but that means that `foo` itself must save and restore `ebx`.

Comment: Ahh. good point. What about this: https://godbolt.org/z/x3xEGK

Comment: Same deal, you may `return b` so `b` has to be kept somewhere.  However I think [this](https://godbolt.org/z/4sn3do) demonstrates the bug.

Comment: @Noah: Incidentally, despite the `noinline, noclone` attributes, clang has still figured out that `bar` doesn't use its third argument and has left `rdx` uninitialized, just as you wanted.  `noipa` doesn't suppress this either.

Answer (score 3):

> ***I am wondering if there is a standard way to achieve this.***
>
> I.e I can probably find a hack for it for any given case. But that
> will require me verifying the assembly each time. I am looking for a
> method that you can basically tell the compiler "pass whatever
> happened to be in register".

No, there is no standard way to achieve it in either C or C++.  Neither of these languages speak to any lower-level function call semantics, nor even acknowledge the existence of CPU registers,<sup>*</sup> and both languages require every function call to provide arguments corresponding to all non-optional parameters (which is simply "all declared parameters" in C).

> For example if I have
>
> ```
> int foo(int a, int b) { 
>     int no_init; 
>     return bar(a, b, no_init); 
> }
> ```

... then you reap **undefined behavior** as a result of using the value of `no_init` while it is indeterminate.  Whatever any particular C or C++ implementation that accepts that at all does with it is non-standard by definition.

If you want to call `bar()`, but you don't care what value is passed as the third argument, then why not just choose a convenient value to pass?  Zero, for example:

```
    return bar(a, b, 0);
```

---

<sup>*</sup>Even the `register` keyword does not do this as far as either language standard is concerned.

Comment: passing 0 will definetly cause an ```xorl %edx, %edx``` which is what I am trying to avoid.

Comment: @Noah, if you want to write in assembly then by all means do so.  But if you write in C or C++ then the language standards provide no basis for your assertion that passing 0 will cause any specific machine instruction to be executed.  The instruction you describe might indeed be executed, but C and C++ do not specify details at that level.

Comment: Fair. My question used wrong word. Instead of "standard" concerning the language convention. I am more so after a method that will work in practice for gcc / clang on x86_64 platform. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @Noah Optimizing compilers like GCC and clang like use undefined behaviour to implement whatever optimizations they can.  At best you're only going to get something that happens to work and liable to break if you make any changes, whether it a different version of the same compiler, different compiler options or even seemingly trivial changes to apparently unrelated source code.

Comment: @Noah Note that `xorl %edx, %edx` is a *zeroing idiom* and is handled entirely in the frontend these days.  The cost is negligible.

Comment: @fuz only if backend is the bottleneck. Often frontend is bottleneck which is why I am trying to avoid it.

Comment: @Noah As far as I know, the decoder cannot decode past a branch, so this really only makes a difference if it would otherwise take an extra cycle to decode the call/jump.  This is quite unlikely.

Comment: @Noah, have you *measured* where the bottlenecks are in your code?  Have you identified a large number of needless `xorl` instructions as contributing a significant amount of overhead?  If not, then you are already *way* down a rabbit hole.  Focus first on using the best algorithms for the problem and writing clear code.  The former will get you a long way toward the best possible performance.  The latter will make your code easier to maintain, and possibly also easier for a compiler to optimize.

Comment: Look into micro-optimizations only when you have identified a specific performance problem and traced it to the code responsible.  And even then, you would be well advised to stick to the semantics described by the language specifications, for doing otherwise is an invitation for bugs.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I would rather come up with a solution to this problem so that every time I modify the code elsewhere potentially changing code alignment I don't need to verify that the ```xorl``` isn't delaying the decoding of my critical path.

Comment: @Noah It sounds like you are trying to program a computer. That is not what C++ is for. C++ is an abstraction, a way to _describe a program_ in a logical sense; the C++ compiler programs the computer for you. I suggest assembly!

Answer (score 2):

Note that if the called function does read its 3rd arg, leaving it unwritten risks creating a false dependency on whatever last used EDX.  For example it might be the result of a cache-miss load, or a long chain of calculations.

GCC is careful to xor-zero to break false dependencies in a lot of cases, e.g. before `cvtsi2ss` (bad ISA design) or `popcnt` (Sandybridge-family quirk).

Usually the xor edx,edx is basically a wasted 2-byte NOP, but it does prevent possible coupling of otherwise-independent dependency chains (critical paths).

If you're sure you want to defeat the compiler's attempt to protect you from that, then Nate's `asm("" :"=r"(var));` is a good way to do an integer version of `_mm_undefined_ps()` that actually leaves a register uninitialized.  (Note that `_mm_undefined_ps` doesn't guarantee leaving an XMM reg unwritten; some compilers will xor-zero one for you instead of fully implementing the false-dependency recklessness that intrinsic was designed to allow for Intel's compiler.)

Comment: Got it. My use case is basically to have an optional user defined 3rd argument and a templated handler function. The only way the 3rd argument would be used is through templated function. Just wanted to provide a default handler that does nothing and has absolutely no overhead for unused feature so shouldnt be an issue here.

Comment: @Noah: Have you considered defining 2 symbols that are aliases of each other for the same function (`weakref` attribute or `extern "C" int foo_2arg(int,int) asm("foo")`?  Or just put 2 separate asm labels on the hand-written asm function so it's 2 totally separate function names that just happen to have the same address?  So the compiler properly knows when it's calling a function that only takes 2 args.

Comment: this is planned to be a header only c++ library so don't think that applies this exact case (also rules out assembly I think given the templating). If I convert it to something that is linked that probably is the way to go though. think Nate Eldredge mentioned this earlier in the comments as well.

Comment: @Noah: So you have a function that definitely does take 3 args, but with some values for the first 2 it never looks at the 3rd?  And you want the caller to not spend any instructions setting up RDX in that case.  Probably doable with weakref to define a 2nd function-signature for the same actual machine code compiled from a C++ function (that's also in the header).  Of if it's header-only and you expect it to all inline, then pass `0` and let the compiler optimize away the unused variable at call-sites where the 3rd arg won't be used.

Comment: Maybe make 3rd-arg-unused a template param if you know it but the compiler would have a hard  time proving it from possible runtime variable values at that call site.

Comment: thought ```weakref``` was only for overriding symbols between seperating linked files. I'll give it a shot though (your sure it would work with templates?). Not particularly familiar with ```weakref``` so ill have to look more into it tmrw.

Comment: @Noah: I forget if you need the full asm symbol name, or if it can mangle a target name for you.  weakref (or maybe some alternative non-weak reference) can be used for making aliases for names in the same ELF object, e.g. glibc uses it to have a "hidden" visibility name for internal calls (that don't go through the PLT and don't support symbol interposition, and thus can inline), and an external name.  e.g. for ISO C library functions that are used internally by glibc, like strlen. So I'm not 100% sure there's a nice way to do this, but hopefully there's something.

Answer (score 1):

Cast the function to have the smaller signature (i.e. fewer parameters):

```
extern int bar(int, int, int);

int foo(int a, int int b) {
    return ((int (*)(int,int))bar)(a, b); 
}
```

Maybe make a macro for 2 parameter bar, and even get rid of `foo`:

```
extern int bar3(int, int, int);

#define bar2(a,b) ((int (*)(int,int))bar3)(a,b)

int userOfBar(int a, int b) { return bar2 (a,b); }
```

https://godbolt.org/z/Gn4a69

Oddly, given the above gcc doesn't touch %edx, but clang does... oh, well.

(Still can't guarantee the compiler won't touch some registers, though, that's its domain.  Otherwise, you can write these functions directly in assembly and avoid the middleperson.)

Comment: Clever. guess maybe I could use an ifdef on gcc / clang and choose between this method and the one I tried.

Comment: This approach produces undefined behavior.